# using regex to find methods in C# code files

Tags: c#, regex, textedit

I have like 30 C# class files that all have the a method with the same name but not the same code inside, I want to change this by searching the C# file for a regex match of the method and whatever is inside. So far my regex can find the first line of the method (thats the easy part) but I cannot figure out how to find the opening curly brace and the closing curly brace with uknown number of characters in between.

Here is my attempt but I'm no expert

```
private void btnDelete_Click\(object sender, EventArgs e\)
\{
\S
\}
```

And this is the method I need to find

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridView1.RowCount <= 0) return;

        this.rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
        currentState = state.delete;

        MessageResult res = new Global.sysMessages.sysMessagesClass().viewMessage(
            MessageType.Warning,
            "Delete Warning",
            "You are about to delete this record from the system forever.\nare you sure you want to continue?",
            ButtonTypes.YesNo,
            MessageDisplayType.Small);

        if (res == MessageResult.Yes)
        {
            delete(rowHandle);
            loadGrid();
        }
        currentState = state.idle;
    }
```

Any help is welcome, Thanks

Comment: This is where Roslyn could help. But in any case, why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve by doing this? What about reflection, will this help?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use Regex to parse code, about 80% of the time it will match things that you didn't intend to.

Comment: Does this need to cater for anonymous methods as well, in which case this is going to get complicated

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas, like I said, I have 30 odd code files that need the method to change, if I can do it in a few minutes then that would be wonderful... but as it is I need to now open up every file, scroll down to find the method and paste the new code in... after about 5x doing this I get horrifically bored...

Comment: @AlphaDelta What other methods are out there other than Regex to find a method and replace the code inside?

Comment: I would say that it is harder and more error prone to automate this than to just do it manually file by file...

Comment: @liquidsnake786 well I guess not? it should find the method and then replace only that method you were searching for... All the code is pretty much the same on all 30 files so if it finds the one then it should work on all 30

Comment: @mortb I know but it is extremely tedious, I have had to do this multiple times when a change was done on one form and had to be implemented on all the others as well. I have a deadline and doing it manually will take far too long.

Comment: If you have 30 methods with the same name in different files and almost the same implementation, shouldn't you instead use some SOLID design principles? And start changing this to a class exposing these methods and that uses sub methods for the differences? This way you only have to change one method that will work for all.

Comment: @woutervs the problem I have with that is simply that some of them have major differences and most of them can change at any given time... some will change while others will not... So making them all refer to a single method will cause further complication in implementation and debugging later on

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
private\s+void\s+btnDelete_Click\s*\(object\s+sender,\s*EventArgs\s+e\)\s*\{.+;\s+\}\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

[Here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sFu9_10jDKg-3-Q3)

#### Discussion

The central problem is how to match the final curly brace. I assume that the `btnDelete_Click` method is not placed at the end of the class. **Otherwise, this regex is useless**.

This regex can be used for quick and dirty work that has a one-time use life span.

Comment: In this case it finds the whole method up to the point where there is a line of code just before the methods ending "}"... I have a line that says "state = states.loading;" it doesn't find that line

Comment: @5tar-Kaster Can you add the method body that contain this line please ?

Comment: I think I'm going to update the question to add the whole delete code, but I'm beginning to think that this may be a tad more difficult than I had first thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
\s*private\svoid\sbtnDelete_Click\(.*?\)\s*\{.+?\}(?!['"].*\}.*['"].*)
```

Don't forgot the DOTALL, ie `.` matches everything including `\n`.

Everything between `\{.+?\}` is the method's code.

### UPDATE:

As pointed out, the above regex will fail, so here is a recursive that seems to do the trick:

```
{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}
```

Also, it will fail if there are `}` inside string vars, something I'm looking into as using parsers for simple jobs can be overkill sometimes :)

Comment: this doesn't find the whole method unfortunaly, if you have an if statement within the method it will stop looking beyond the "}"of the if...

Answer (score -1):

If the method isn't at the end of the file and you know the scope of the following method (in this example "private"), you could just use

```
void btnDelete_Click(.|\n)*(?=private)
```